# Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is what I do:

```
import BSTableViewReorder
```

and get the following error:

> Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3

What can I do to make it compile? I did:

```
Edit > Convert -> Current Swift Syntax
```

**Using Xcode 8 and macOS Sierra.**

For Both: the target and the project I have the following settings of `Use Legacy Swift Language Version`

[image]
[image]

The project is my pod for cocoapods dependencies. I just converted project to Swift 3.0 but it does not compile.

Comment: Change Use Legacy Swift Language Version to NO. That will let you use swift 3 compiled modules.

Comment: Change for what target? For both?

Comment: Try changing it for both. From what I understand you should only enable it if you want to use SWIFT 2.3

Comment: @EugenDimboiu Ok, I changed it like you said, but... when I type `pod spec lint BSTableViewReorder.podspec` I got `The spec did not pass validation, due to 49 errors and 6 warnings.`. You know what is wrong? My project successfully compiles on iphone and works.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile? are you sure you're targeting IOS and swift 3 in the podfile ?

Comment: @EugenDimboiu I updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123869/discussion-between-eugen-dimboiu-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to change the `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `NO` - this makes sure your project will use swift 3.

If you want to package your project as a POD (for cocoapods) you'll need to add a file named .swift-version (containing 1 single line, "3.0"). 
This will tell cocoapods to use the swift 3 compiler.

Everything should work after this changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any third party frameworks just update them once for Xcode 8.1 and change the Use Legacy Swift Language Version to NO.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the framework developers added this line in the code that was intended for the `Podfile`:

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' # or '3.0'
```

as you can see, they defaulted to '2.3', which caused problems because i was running 3.0. simply removing the `'2.3' # or` and leaving the `'3.0'` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the above suggestions don't work for you try deleting ~Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData