# IOS Charts Module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts, swift2

I'm working on a project which is coded in swift 2.3 and I'm trying to use IOS charts  (by danielgindi))in a new UIViewController.When I try to import Charts I get the following error saying "Module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3". How can I overcome this issue and implement IOS Charts in Swift 2.3. My requirement is to use a pie chart to display data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lower version of it that is written in swift 2.3

Something like this in your podfile: `pod 'Charts', '2.3.1'`, v2.3.1 support swift 2.3, v3.0+ seems to support swift 3

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new ti swift, so u saying installing pod 'Charts', '2.3.1' would solve my issue ?

Comment: Are u using cocoapod? just replace `pod 'Charts'` with the one above then reinstall, it should work

Comment: No I'm not using pods for now. I just drag and dropped the library as in the tutorial. So what would u suggest sir ?

Comment: Then download [this](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/v2.3.1) and replace the one u having

Comment: this is the exact one i downloaded

Comment: it's lower version should work with swift 2.3, just download it again, it's different from what you are having

Answer (score 0):

You can need to change version of pod in pod file

OR

use following github demo and install pod

https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts

Comment: I installed pod 'SwiftCharts', '~> 0.4' as it suggests, but same issue even after a clean build

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162175/module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-2-3

Comment: yes swift 2.3 and I'm looking a way to use IOS Charts