# RealmSwift: Module Compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported with Swift 3.0.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I am trying to use RealmSwift with my Xcode project. I have used it several times before, but since the last Xcode (8.2) update I keep getting the same error "Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2".

I have tried installing it through cocoapods and I have tried installing it directly. I have tried changing the IOS. I have updated the pods and downloaded the latest version, but nothing is working.

I looked at similar issues posted on here with no luck:

[Realm's Swift module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731926/realms-swift-module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-1)

[Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162175/module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-2-3)

[Migrating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572554/migrating-from-swift-2-3-to-swift-3-with-dependencies)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Its not possible until they (Realm Dev)  release sdk compatible with Swift 3.0.2. You should use Objective C sdk and use it by Bridging Header.

Comment: @Poles thank you. I can't seem to get it working, can you post an example?

Comment: Are you using Objective C sdk? If yes, then follow this https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#using-realm-objectivec-from-swift

Comment: I cant seem to get the Objective C sdk to work? I installed it the same way that I would install realmSwift, then I used the #import "Realm/RLMRealm.h" statement, but it's not working.

Comment: Please check the path `Objective C Bridging Header` file in build settings. Also clean and run your project without writing any code in swift file.

Comment: Also have you included `RLMSupport.swift` file which is inside the https://static.realm.io/downloads/objc/realm-objc-2.1.2.zip zip file?

Comment: @Poles Yes i have included the RLMSupport.swift file and the objective c briding header is linked correctly. The issue i am having is the #import 'Realm/Realm.h" in the header file says "file not found".

Comment: Try #import 'Realm.h" only. And clean the build folder.

Comment: @Poles that didnt work either. I used both the cocoapods installation and the manual installation. Any idea when the next update is coming out?

Comment: Not really. But hope it will come out soon.

Comment: I imported realm Objective C framework and integrated in swift using briding header with `#import 'Realm/Realm.h"` and its working correctly.

Comment: May I know have you added the `Realm.framework` in Build phases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132141/discussion-between-fushy-and-poles).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Swift 3.0.0 toolchain as a temporary workaround until the 3rd party framework has been updated to the latest version. Swift 3.0.0 is available here:
https://swift.org/download/

After downloading it, you can choose to use Swift 3.0.0 from the menubar:
[image]

Thought this might help anyone facing the same with other 3rd party frameworks that haven't yet been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Realm.framework` in **Build Phases** by using `+` -> `New Copy File Phase`. Follow the image below.

[image]

And import `'Realm/Realm.h"` in `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

Swift binaries aren't compatible across different versions. Swift 3.0 and Swift 3.0.2. although virtually identical are still different binaries.

We try to push out new builds of Realm Swift to support new versions of Xcode as soon as possible. At the time of writing, we're now shipping 3.0.2 binaries of Realm Swift.

So as long as you've updated to the latest version of Realm Swift, this shouldn't be a problem anymore: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started